# Correct php syntax

Tags: php, sql

```
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO tool (title,details) VALUES (:title,:details) ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':details'=>$details,
                  ':title'=>$title));
```

Been having trouble with this all day, I've finally got it down to this.  If I use the above code, it will just add a new post to the database.  This is supposed to be used for editing a post, so obviously I need to edit existing information:

```
// query
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET['story']);
$sql = "UPDATE  tool SET (title,details) VALUES (:title,:details) WHERE id = $post";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':details'=>$details,
                  ':title'=>$title));
```

'id' is a column in the database.  I need it to update the title, and details, for that specific post.  I'm just not sure what syntax I'm supposed to be using here.

Thanks for any answers!

===== Second question:

Now I'm back to my old error.  Whenever I edit a post, it will lose the title and details, only once.  The first time I edit the post, I lose all information, but the rest of the times it will work just fine.  Any idea why?  Heres the code:

Form from the edit page(may or may not be important, I don't know):

```
$name = $_SESSION['Username'];
if (in_array($name, $allowedposters)) {
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tool WHERE id = $post");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){


$title= $row['title'];
$details= $row['details'];
$date= $row['date'];
$author= $row['author'];
$id= $row['id'];



echo "<a href=story.php?id=";
echo $post;
echo ">Cancel edit</a> <br><br><b>";
echo $title;
echo "</b> <br><br>";
echo '
<form action="edit-new.php?story=';
echo $id;
echo '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea rows="1" cols="60" name="title" wrap="physical" maxlength="100">';
echo $title;
echo '</textarea><br>';
?>



<textarea rows="30" cols="60" name="details" wrap="physical" maxlength="10000">
<?php 
echo $details;
echo '</textarea><br>';

echo '<label for="file">Upload featured image:</label><br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />';
echo'<br><input type="submit" />';
}

} else {
  echo "Not enough permissions.";
}
?>
```

Here is the SQL, inserting into DB:

```
<?php
   $post = htmlspecialchars($_GET['story']);
   $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
   $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
      echo "B<br>";
      echo $_POST['title'];
      echo '<br>';
      echo $_POST['details'];
      echo $post;
      echo "<br><br>";


// configuration
$dbtype     = "mysql";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "zzzz";
$dbuser     = "zzzzz";
$dbpass     = "zzzzzz";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data


// query
$sql = "UPDATE  tool SET title=:title, details=:details WHERE id = :postid";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
  ':details'=>$details,
  ':title'=>$title,
  ':postid' => $post
));




?>
```

Comment: how "random" is the information?

Comment: Sorry, I was not thinking when I wrote that part.  Re-read it.

Comment: Just by the way, if you're sending back entire stories, perhaps a POST would be more appropriate than a GET, and (this is just me) I'd name the parameter "storyid" instead of "story" to save a bit of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your sql [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html)

```
$sql = "UPDATE  tool SET title=:title, details=:details WHERE id = :postid";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
  ':details'=>$details,
  ':title'=>$title,
  ':postid' => $post
));
```

Comment: This works as planned, but now I'm back to my old error.  Whenever I edit a post, it will lose the title and details, only once.  The first time I edit the post, I lose all information, but the rest of the times it will work just fine.  Any idea why?

Comment: your error is somewhere else I guess you didn't passed new values for edited post in form or something similar.. hard to tell without code maybe ask new question.